# Manual .apk updates failing randomly (downloaded from server)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, apk, auto-update

Application updates happen in the app on startup. The app checks on a server for the latest version and downloads to storage the latest .apk file if a newer version is available. The app then initiates the update process.

What happens sometimes is that after downloading and trying to install the update a message comes up. "Parse error. There is a problem parsing the package." We have 60 odd android devices in the field and the updates work on most of them except for about 10 of them.

Then on a new project that utilises the same update process, we have tablets refusing to update with the same error message. This happens repeatedly on the same tablet, although on another tablet (different brand and OS) it works fine.

There appears to be no correlation between the device brand or the OS version. On the tablet we have it is apparent that the .apk file does not download completely. Doing a manual download and update from the internet browser works though.

So to try and summarise on some device the .apk file download does not finish and installation fails. Could this be because of network bandwidth constraints? But then surely those 10 tablets in the field should update at some point since the update process is started on every application start and I can see the apps are used again and again but not updated.

Sorry about rambling on, but there is a lot of information I am trying to understand. Could these lines of code below be stopping the download after 5 seconds? What is the difference between the two timeouts?

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
```

Below is the standard update `AsyncTask`. Any help would be appreciated. I am a bit baffled at the moment and time is not on my side.

```
   private class UpdateDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpClient httpclient;
        HttpGet httpget;
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpEntity httpentity;
        OutputStream outputStream;

        protected void onPreExecute () {

            //do not lock screen or drop connection to server on login
            activity.getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);                  
            //initiate progress dialogue to block user input during initial data retrieval
            ProcessingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please Wait", "Downloading Updates", true,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... nothing) {

            try {
                //set timeouts for httpclient
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

                //setup http get
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);             
                httpget = new HttpGet(uriApk);

                // Execute HTTP Get Request
                response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                httpentity = response.getEntity();

                //create location to store apk file
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
                File file = new File(path);
                file.mkdirs();  //if download folder not already exist
                File outputFile = new File(file, apkName);

                //write downloaded file to location
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, false);
                httpentity.writeTo(outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                return "success";
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                return "error: " + e.toString();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //check if result null or empty
            if (result.length() == 0 || result == null) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Could Not Download Updates, Please Try Again. Closing Application.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                activity.finish();
            }           
            //update downloaded
            if (result.equals("success"))   {
                //install downloaded .apk file
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + apkName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                activity.startActivity(intent);               
                //activity.finish();
            }
            //update not downloaded
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Could Not Download Updates, Please Try Again. Closing Application.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
                activity.finish();
            }           

            //close update dialog
            try {
                ProcessingDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            //release screen lock
            activity.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I added the following code and also increased the time-outs to 30000 ms.

```
httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; SCH-I800 Build/FROYO) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
```

Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.